# How to apply this Typo3 patch?

Tags: typo3, patch

I would like to execute a patch for a security bug on Typo3. You get more information [here](https://typo3.org/teams/security/security-bulletins/typo3-core/typo3-core-sa-2016-013/).

I have downloaded the [zip file](https://typo3.org/fileadmin/security-team/bug76231/fix_76231.zip) where I find a .sh file and many .diff files. I guess I have to run the .sh file but on which directory do I have to upload those files and how can I execute the .sh file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to unpack the zip file to your server.
Then SSH into the unzipped directory.
in this directory, run the following commands:

```
$ chmod a+x ./fix_76231.sh
$ ./fix_76231.sh [rootPath]
```

This did the trick for me.
Bear in mind that [rootPath] should be the full path to the TYPO3 sources on your server.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!